# FIND operands and order of arguments

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find, ksh

I have a find command that I am unsure if I am placing my arguments correctly.

```
find / -xdev -size -size -262144000c -o -type d \( -name .snapshot -o -name man -o -name Man -o -fstype mvfs \) -prune -o -type f
```

I only want to find files under 250MB that are not in .snapshot, man directories or on MVFS filesystems.

Do I need to place my size command in the brackets?
Do I need to use a -a instead of a -o?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this?: `find / -type d \( -name .snapshot -o -name man -o -name Man -o -fstype mvfs \) -prune -o -xdev -size -262144000c -type f -print` . `-a` is implied between expressions if `-o` isn't specified.

Comment: I suggest keeping the `-xdev` at the beginning (after the `/`).  If you have `-xdev`, I believe you don't need `-fstype`.  Also, you could change `-name man -o -name Man` to `-name "[Mm]an"`.

Comment: @crw Please post this as an Answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Copying my comment to the question into an answer...

`find / -type d \( -name .snapshot -o -name man -o -name Man -o -fstype mvfs \) -prune -o -xdev -size -262144000c -type f -print`

`-a` is implied between expressions if `-o` isn't specified.

(I have insufficient reputation to create/edit comments, my comment migrated with the question from [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com). However, perhaps @Scott can answer and receive benefit for his contribution, I learnt something. You should message him in the same way. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

[crw's answer](https://superuser.com/a/479432/150988) is good.  Copying *my* comment into a supplementary answer:

- I suggest keeping the `-xdev` at the beginning (after the `/`).
- If you have `-xdev`, I believe you don't need `-fstype`.
- Also, you could change  `-name man -o -name Man`  to  `-name "[Mm]an"`.